# "Set tipping point"

Tags: word-usage

Reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/debt-nearly-double-2050-cbo-223255430.html) there is a line saying,

> Still, CBO Director Phillip Swagel said in a statement that a crisis is not immediately at hand. “There is no **set tipping point** at which a fiscal crisis becomes likely or imminent, nor is there an identifiable point at which interest costs as a percentage of GDP become unsustainable,” Swagel said. “But as the debt grows, the risks become greater.”

I kind of feel it, but it is a bit ambigeuos to me.

Is the meaning of the verb "tipping" defined at [**this dictionary,**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tip), intransitive, 2, "lean, slant"?

Thank you for your help and kindly be reminded my next look might be later because I have to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither *set* nor *tipping* are used as verbs in that phrase:

> **tipping point** noun
>
> : the critical point in a situation, process, or system beyond which a significant and often unstoppable effect or change takes place

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tipping%20point

> **set** adjective
>
> 3 : fixed by authority, appointment, or agreement
> // The wedding is *set* [=scheduled] for early June
> // Students can drop in during *set* [=designated] office hours
>
> 5a : immovable, rigid
> // *set* frown
>
> 6 : settled, persistent
> // *set* defiance

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set

So, all together, the sentence means: *there is no predetermined/well-established/consistent point when a fiscal crisis tips over (crosses a threshold) into an inevitability*.  Or, put more simply: *we can't identify the conditions that make a fiscal crisis likely or sure to happen*.